# isin() function using Spark / Java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, isin

I have the following two dataframes .

```
dataframe1
┌────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────┐
│idZones     │Longitude    │latitude      |
├────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────┤
|[50,30,10]  |-7.073781666 |33.826661     |
└────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┘
dataframe2
┌────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────┐
│id          │col1         │col2          │
├────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────┤
│10          │aaaaaaaaaaaa │bb32          │
│90          │ppp          │cc20          │
└────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┘
```

I want the following output

```
┌────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────┐
│id          │col1         |col2          │
├────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────┤
│10          │aaaaaaaaaaaa │bb32          │
└────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┘
```

I use the following code

```
 dataframe1.join(dataframe2,dataframe2.col("id").isin(dataframe1.col("idZones")));
```

**Note the idZones column is an array[int]**

I get this error

```
cannot resolve '(`id` IN (dataframe1.`idZones`))' due to data type mismatch: Arguments must be same type but were: int != array<int>;;
```

I need your help

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rayan suggested, you can use explode before you join dataframe1 with dataframe2

Creating dataframes -

```
val dataframe1 = Seq((Array(50,30,10),-7,30)).toDF("idZones","longitude","latitude")

val dataframe2 = Seq((10,"aaaaa","bb32"),(90,"ppp","cc20")).toDF("id","col1","col2")
```

Explosion logic -

```
dataframe1.select(explode($"idZones").as("idZones")).join(dataframe2, $"idZones" === dataframe2("id")).show(false)
```

Output -

```
+-------+---+-----+----+
|idZones|id |col1 |col2|
+-------+---+-----+----+
|10     |10 |aaaaa|bb32|
+-------+---+-----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `isin` with `array_contains`.

```
dataframe1.join(dataframe2, expr("array_contains(idZones, id)"))
```

(fixed code, thanks @Shantanu Kher)

Another way, you can just `explode` `dataframe1.col("idZones")`, and then do a join.

Comment: thank you for your reply .But  Cannot resolve method 'array_contains' in 'Column' , and I want to take the lines of dataframe2 witch id is in idZones.

Comment: correct syntact for array_contains - dataframe1.join(dataframe2, expr("array_contains(idZones, id)")).show(false)